# Delete character using css that doesn't defined in element

Tags: css

I have to hide character using only css, this character doesn't any html tag.
[image]

is it possible?

I have acces only to css through confluence settings and I can't change html. If some one there did play with confluence css space styling he will undestand what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```css
.top-macro.top-service-nav{visibility: hidden;}
.top-macro.top-service-nav a{visibility: visible;}
```